# can set.seed be made to automatically return to the initial seed after each time it is used in R?

Tags: r, reproducible-research

I have my seed set to 1981 in R.
I have several lines of code that run functions that use the random seed.
however, the seed does not stay at 1981.
after being used the first time, it is changed and so each subsequent function has a different seed.
how can I keep this from happening?

Comment: just use set.seed() before each time you need the seed reset?

Comment: Thank you. this is the solution I am currently using. I am looking for something more elegant, perhaps something I can place in the original set.seed function or something I can do in global options?

Comment: I extremely doubt it. this is one line. how is that inelegant? it's also extremely readable.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found is to call the set.seed() function before each function I want to run it on.
It works but is not very elegant.

Comment: If you don't want to repeat, put set.seed() into the function you are calling if you call the same function repeatedly.

Comment: That is an interesting solution. I think it would work and I will include that in the next iteration.